# Cross compile OpenCV for a RaspberryPI

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cross-compiling

i've been trying to make an application that combines Qt and OpenCV, and then deploy this application on a RaspberryPi.
i managed to cross compile Qt to run applications i built on my host machine on the RaspberryPi but whenever i want to use OpenCV with it, i fail to get to work. The first time i had incompatible libraries with ARM (they were x86-64) and now when i installed ARM version of OpenCV i get this error in Qt Creator (cannot find -lm).
Can u please tell me how to cross compile OpenCV as well ? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried compiling OpenCV directly on the Pi? 
https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/26/install-opencv-4-on-your-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @ShawnRamirez yes i have but i don't know where to go from there

Comment: Here is [link]https://wiki.qt.io/Create_Qt_on_Raspberry_Pi